# How to sort scatter plot by decreasing values of y axis using pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe df1 containing two columns freq and RN with the data sorted according to ascending order by freq.

```
    In [2]: df1.head()
    Out[2]: 
       freq  RN
    147 1   181
    56  1   848
    149 1   814
    25  1   829
```

I want to plot a scatter plot with X axis as RN and y axis as freq where the X values are arranged in ascending order of the y values ie. I want the x axis to be arranged as 841,848,835,... as given in df1 which has been sorted according to ascending order of freq values.

Now if I write  `plt.scatter('RN', 'freq',data=df1)` the output x axis I get is not sorted by the ascending order of freq. It is arranged in its own natural ascending order like 800,801,...,860.

**Note:**  `plt.bar('RN', 'freq',data=df1)` works in the correct way as I want.

[image]

How Do I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If the `RN` column is numeric, the plot API will sort it numerically.
- This can be done if you set the `RN` column type to `str`.

  - This works best if the values in `RN` are unique. If they are not unique, all the `freq` values for a non-unique `RN` will be plotted together.
  - If `RN` is not unique, there's no way for the plot API to differential one value from another.

### Non-Unique RN (a)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create test data
np.random.seed(365)
data = {'freq': np.random.randint(20, size=(20,)), 'RN': np.random.randint(800, 900, size=(20,))}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert RN to a str type
df.RN = df.RN.astype(str)

# sort freq
df.sort_values('freq', ascending=True, inplace=True)

# plot
plt.scatter('RN', 'freq', data=df)
```

[image]

### Non-Unique RN (b)

- Use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` to group non-unique RNs together

```py
# create test data
# create test data
np.random.seed(365)
data = {'freq': np.random.randint(20, size=(20,)), 'RN': np.random.randint(800, 900, size=(20,))}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert RN to a str type
df.RN = df.RN.astype(str)

# combine non-unique RN with groupby and sort by freq
dfg = df.groupby('RN', as_index=False)['freq'].sum().sort_values('freq')

# plot
plt.scatter('RN', 'freq', data=dfg)
```

[image]

### Unique RN

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create test data
np.random.seed(365)
data = {'freq': np.random.randint(20, size=(20,)), 'RN': np.arange(800, 820)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert RN to a str type
df.RN = df.RN.astype(str)

# sort `freq`
df.sort_values('freq', ascending=True, inplace=True)

# plot
plt.scatter('RN', 'freq', data=df)
```

[image]